Is it possible to use Dynamic Parameter with SqlQuery in Cosmos DB input binding
Is it possible to have parameter passed to SQLQuery if yes how.
public async Task<string> SomeFunction
    ([ActivityTrigger] string input,
    [CosmosDBInput(
    databaseName:"dbname",
    containerName:"containername",
    SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.prop = {para} or "@para",
    Connection = "DBConnection"
    )]
    List<someobject> pages,
    FunctionContext executionContext){}


This question is similar to: Parameterized Input with Document Fields with Cosmos DB. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

or: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/parameterized-queries

This question is more related to Azure Functions binding expressions.
Yes, you can have your query dynamically have values injected based on the Trigger. The binding expression used in the Query should match attributes on the Trigger object.
In your case you have [ActivityTrigger] string input which is a string. It doesn't look like you can access any property of that input to bind in the Query?
For example, with an HTTPTrigger you can do:
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "MyAPI/{deviceId}")] HttpRequest req,
[CosmosDB(
    databaseName: "myDb",
    containerName: "myContainer",
    SqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM c WHERE c.deviceId = {deviceId}",
    Connection= "DBConnection"
    )] IEnumerable<someobject> items

